# Creating an interactive wallpaper using python

Tags: python, windows, interactive, wallpaper

I'll break my question in to two parts.

First of all, is it even possible to create an interactive wallpaper(a wallpaper that can interact with the mouse, maybe when you click the background reacts, or moves or basically anything that can be considered interactive. Or perhaps responses to the current mouse location) for windows 7 using python? I'm looking to create something like Okozo ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZvBXO_9Qjo)'s an example)

Secondly, is there anyone that can point me in the right direction? I'm not really sure where to begin, or even the file type that is used to do this.

Comment: Maybe this is not formulated very well, and maybe it isn't hitting SO in the belly, but it is an interesting question; it belongs in fact to a "hard to define" category of questions that this community can answer in a heartbeat and be of tremendous help with; oftentimes, someone will have the will and ability to do something, but be blocked by tiny technical detail, or not knowing the jargon necessary for a search, etc... it is a pity that this question was put on hold with none of the "judges" willing to offer a hint of a pointer, if only where else to ask!